# Beautify Ruby source code with Geany

Tags: ruby, code-formatting, pretty-print, geany

How can I get [Geany](http://www.geany.org/) to beautify or prettify ruby code? What's the distinction between the two, anyhow?

My main interest is indents, that the indenting is consistent and correct.

I would like to integrate the [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-beautify) into Geany if there's no plugin.

See also:
[SO question 1194185](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1194185/where-can-i-find-a-decent-ruby-source-beautifier/14000532#14000532)
[PlugIn for Ruby Refactoring](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.editors.geany.devel/7057)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geany allows this to be handled by external tools, for example astyle. Go to `Edit->Format->Send Selection to->Set Custom Commands` to set external tools up and play with `astyle --style=gnu -FpPn`, sort and others. As long as the script mentioned above is able to be ran from the command line, I guess it will also be possible to set it up as such an external tool.

For ruby in particular, you can use `rbeautify`.